# findViewById causes NullPointerException for no apparent reason

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android development. My app is compiling perfectly fine (no errors, no warnings), but it crashes on launch. I have diagnosed the cause of the crash to be a NullPointerException, and I discovered that if I remove `TextView output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputbox);` as well as all the lines depending on this declaration, the app launches fine. I did research (both on and off Stack Exchange, and about 5 pages of Google results) and none of the solutions I have found worked, which is why I am asking this question. I have ran `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` before `TextView output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputbox);` and `outputbox` is declared in activity_main.xml. This is not a duplicate of the existing questions because the answers to the other ones did not solve my problem.

Comment: Post your .xml and activity code.

Comment: Post you .xml code

Comment: You're rarely going to find a ready-made solution for any given scenario. The key is *understanding* the problem and *adapting* the solution.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand difference between run-time exceptions and compilation errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

most probably your declaration and initialization of the variable `output` is in the class. This is not going to work. The method `findViewById` will work only after the `setContentView` method has been invoked. That is why you have to declare your variable in the class, but initialize it in the method `onCreate` immediately after the `setContentView` method:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView output;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputbox)
    }

}
```

The method `findViewById` searches for your component in the xml. For this to work, you have to point out what xml file will this Activity be using. This is done in the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` command. It is a common mistake, so no worries :)

Comment: My declaration and initialization were both in the class, on the same line, but AFTER the method. Why exactly wouldn't that work?

Comment: The declaration and initialization of variables in the class occur before ANY of the methods are invoked. So the initialization would be the first code to be run in your class. Read about the Activity Lifecycle - when the activity is visualized on the screen, the onCreate method is invoked and THEN the findViewById method would work. Never use findViewById in the class, only in methods that are called AFTER onCreate :)

Comment: I will read about the Activity Lifecycle as soon as possible. Thank you for the help.